# Не могу выяснить из-за чего ошибка TypeError: 'module' object is not callable ошибка в выделенной строчке

Tags: python

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
import time
import vk
import requests
import random
import sys
from colorama import init
import colorama
from os import system, name
import os
init(autoreset=True)

class color:
    Red = '\033[91m'
    Green = '\033[1;32m'
    Yellow = '\033[93m'
    Blue = '\033[94m'
    Magenta = '\033[95m'
    Cyan = '\033[96m'
    White = '\033[97m'
    Grey = '\033[90m'
    BOLD = '\033[1m'
    ITALIC = '\033[3m'
    UNDERLINE = '\033[4m'
    END = '\033[0m'
    
# define our clear function
def clear():

    # for windows
    if name == 'nt':
        _ = system('cls')

    # for mac and linux(here, os.name is 'posix')
    else:
        _ = system('clear')

#vars
color.Cyan

color.END
infinite = 3
token_passed = 0

while token_passed == 0:
    token = input('Введите токен: ')
    color.END
    session = vk.session(access_token=token) # ОШИБКА!!!
    api = vk.API(session ,v='5.92', lang='ru')
```

Ошибка:

```
session = vk.session(access_token=token)
TypeError: 'module' object is not callable
```

Answer (score 1):

Насколько я смог понять, `vk.session` - это модуль внутри модуля `vk`, поэтому такая ошибка выходит при попытке вызвать его как метод (функцию). Вероятно, вы хотели вызвать метод `vk.Session` (с большой буквы), но этот метод устарел, его больше нет в в этой библиотеке, хотя в старых примерах кода он и встречается. Я так понял, сессия больше не нужна, нужно сразу вызывать `API`:

```
api = vk.API(access_token=token)
```